# How can I get logs for Cloud Functions that violate a Stackdriver alerting policy?

Tags: google-cloud-functions, stackdriver, google-cloud-logging

I am using Cloud Functions on Google Cloud Platform. I have set up a Stackdriver alerting policy to send me notifications when those functions exceed an execution time threshold.

I would like to specifically get the logs for function instances that violate this policy. But when I click on the "Logs" link on the Policy Violation page of the Stackdriver user interface, it shows me all the logs for that function.

How can I filter Cloud Function logs to only get logs of instances which violate a Stackdriver alerting policy?

**Update:**

To clarify, my intention is to get the text logs of instances that violate a policy, rather than a summary metric.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter on Cloud Function logs of an instance which violate a stackdriver alerting policy, then you need to create a "custom metric"  (Stackdriver > Logs-based metrics > Create Metric) to get the execution time of a particular function.

You can find more detailed information in this article, [Getting Google Cloud Functions times in Stackdriver](https://medium.com/@duhroach/getting-google-cloud-functions-times-in-stackdriver-61ec1b33a92).

However, the custom metric will parse the logs and give Stackdriver a number you can put in a chart. After that, you can set an alert for that chart.

Comment: Thank you for your input Mahboob, but my understanding is that this will return a summary metric/visualization of the execution times. My intention is to get the text from the logs that violate the policy. Are you aware of a way to do this?

Comment: Thank you for your information. Would you please describe the issue more, this will allow me to simulate the issue on test environment?